How to use JSON of array of integers in IN clause MySQL
Because of differences between MySQL and MariaDB in storing JSON object, I prefer using text type of column, like in MariaDB. I have a table of list of industries, with just id and title columns.
Articles have a column called industries, with array of ids for which industries that article belongs. For example, [1,3,6].
When I check if article is part of single industry, it is easy done with JSON_CONTAINS function.
However, I need to load all industry titles for given article in a single query, and just cant figure out.
For example:
select 
   A.*, 
   (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`title`) from `industries` where `id` in (SOME_JSON_FUNCTION(A.industries)) as IndustryList 
from `articles` A 
where A.`id`=1;

When I use, for example
select 
   A.*, 
   (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`title`) from `industries` where `id` in (1,3,6)) as IndustryList 
from `articles` A 
where A.`id`=1;

it works like a charm.
Instead of SOME_JSON_FUNCTION I have used all known JSON functions for mysql but none of them works (or IDK how to use them properly). Any idea how to do this? Or is it even possible?

Why not normalize it and make an own table for relation of article to industry?

becasue not only articles will have relation to industry... blogs, news and some other sections as well

or eventually relation table with section type (article, blog, new), section item id, industry id ? and instead of json to use for example SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(title) from industrieswhereid in (select industry_id from relations where relation_type='article' and item_id=A.id) ?

Here's one way to do this:
select A.*, (
  SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`title`) FROM `industries` 
  WHERE `id` MEMBER OF (A.industries)
) as IndustryList 
from `articles` A where A.`id`=1;

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#operator_member-of
A second solution that works in both MySQL and MariaDB:
SELECT a.*, GROUP_CONCAT(title) AS IndustryList
FROM `articles` AS a
CROSS JOIN JSON_TABLE(a.industries, '$[*]' COLUMNS (industry_id INT PATH '$')) AS j
JOIN industries i ON j.industry_id = i.id
WHERE a.`id`=1;

MySQL demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/lVw_fs8y
MariaDB demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/WotxEEX6

MEMBER OF is not present in MariaDB server.

Right, but you asked how to do it in MySQL. It's inevitable that you sometimes need a different solutions when you use different, incompatible RDBMS implementations. Writing so-called portable SQL is impractical.

True. I have switched already to relations table proposed by @Thallius

I agree that using a normalized design is better.
